# I need help making/building a catkin package

Tags: ros, python, catkin-package, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let me start off by saying that I have read the tutorials on how to make a package and how to build it, but I seem to be too stupid to get it right because it never works. I am running ros groovy on Ubuntu 12.04lts. This is what I am trying to do, build a package that can be started by a launch file. The package is a python script that reads a serial line form a arduino and publishes it on a ros topic. The package that I want to make is all based around "encoder_feedback.py". After I build the package, I try to run it with

```
walle@wallebase:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun encoder_feedback encoder_feedback.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/walle/catkin_ws/src/encoder_feedback/scripts/encoder_feedback.py", line 4, in <module>
    import rospy
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .client import spin, myargv, init_node, \
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/client.py", line 46, in <module>
    import yaml
ImportError: No module named yaml
```

What do I need to do to build a working package? Let me know if I need to post the .py code or include more info. Thanks for any help you can give.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61632/i-need-help-making/building-a-catkin-package./) by [packrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3685/packrat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-04-26

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-04-26**:
Do you have a run_depend for **python-yaml** in your `package.xml`?

**Comment by [packrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3685/packrat/) on 2013-04-27**:
No I don't. just <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend><build_depend>rospy</build_depend><run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend><run_depend>rospy</run_depend>

**Comment by [packrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3685/packrat/) on 2013-04-27**:
All I am importing is
import serial
import time
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Int32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you seen this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/11557/importerror-no-module-named-yaml/)? Try this and comment your results...

---

Originally posted by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) with karma: 756 on 2013-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [packrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3685/packrat/) on 2013-04-27**:
walle@wallebase:~$ sudo apt-get install python-yaml
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python-yaml is already the newest version.
python-yaml set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-04-27**:
check
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
and
/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
for python-yaml

**Comment by [packrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3685/packrat/) on 2013-04-28**:
Both pythons have yaml

**Comment by [packrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3685/packrat/) on 2013-05-04**:
Any ideas?

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-05-04**:
Can I download your code for try to run it... Do you have the package in a repo?